# How to add a python module (Pillow) as a relative module to a python project without using PIP or installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I need to use a module (Pillow) without using PIP or installing it. Consequently, I have to move the module somehow to the project directory and include it there. Unfortunately, I am not originally a Python programmer and not so fluent with the way modules are imported. I guess, the module must contain compiled libraries and scripts.
So, I downloaded the Pillow installer with the binaries for Python3 (Windows) and extracted the files. The directory hierarchy is more or less like this:

```
D:\pillow_421\PLATLIB
D:\pillow_421\PLATLIB\PIL
D:\pillow_421\PLATLIB\PIL\__pycache__
D:\pillow_421\PLATLIB\Pillow-4.2.1-py3.6.egg-info
D:\pillow_421\SCRIPTS
```

Now I wonder how to import the module just by referring to the extracted directory. I wrote a small script to test the import. It does not execute because I get a `ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'`. Does someone know what's the issue?

```
import sys
sys.path.append("D:\pillow_421\PLATLIB")

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test.bmp")
```

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why can't you install Pillow via `pip` or manually?

Comment: you can use pip + virtualenv, but you can't just use the installer by itself. especially for something like pillow, which IIRC has binaries in it, that have to be compiled against the correct python version (or install a wheel/windows installer) and need to be in a particular place....

Comment: In the installer the packages must be build already, otherwise it would not be an installer. PIP is btw also not installed on this machine and cannot.